# Open not index page with Framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

I try to open link with Framework7.
For example I need to open

http://name.com/about.html

But it open about.html without Framework7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to quote a paragraph from the documentation of Framework7.

https://framework7.io/docs/pages-ajax.html

> By default Framework7 will load all links using Ajax, except links with additional external class (`<a href="somepage.html" class="external">`) and links with not correct href attribute (when it is empty or #).
>   This behavior could be changed by passing ajaxLinks parameter on App initialization

Make sure you have put the additional `class="external"` to your link if you want to load an external link using Framework7.